# Comparison Query For Last 1000 Records

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, query-optimization

I'm looking to compare users in a database based on their last 1000 actions.  The basic structure of the query is as follows:

```
SELECT p.id, p2.id, ROUND(AVG(1000 + ABS(p2.ss - p.ss)/6.1 * -50)) AS sim_score
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM p WHERE id = 519000 ORDER BY p_date DESC LIMIT 0,1000) p, 
(SELECT * FROM p WHERE id = 279000 ORDER BY p_date DESC LIMIT 0,1000) p2
```

In this case I specify both users (519000 and 279000).  This will return one record with each ID and a similarity score.  What are my options for returning one record for every user comparison (u^2-u) in the  database, with the goal of dumping this result in another table?  I can see using nested cursors in a nightly batch job, but I'm hoping there is something more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create tables of the last 1,000 actions for each user using a rank variable and then a group by to compare each user.  Notice the where condition at the bottom to make sure you don't duplicate your comparisons.

A note on efficiency:  The query in the original question takes about 1 second to execute.  When adding one of the tables below, the execution time takes 30 minutes.  The second table likely balloons the query to about 450 minutes (I haven't confirmed).  So, while this answer works, I'm still looking for something that works quicker.

```
SELECT p.id, p2.id, ROUND(AVG(1000 + ABS(p2.ss - p.ss)/6.1 * -50)) AS sim_score FROM 

(SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.id, 
    (CASE p.id
    WHEN @curPit 
    THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curPit := p.id END) AS rank
FROM pitches p, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curPit := '') r 
ORDER BY  p.id, p.p_date DESC) n WHERE rank <= 1000) p, 

(SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.id, 
    (CASE p.id
    WHEN @curPit 
    THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curPit := p.id END) AS rank
FROM pitches p, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curPit := '') r 
ORDER BY  p.id, p.p_date DESC) n WHERE rank <= 1000) p2

WHERE p.id < p2.id
GROUP BY p.id, p2.id
```